# How to set up deployerConfigContext.xml to add attributes to cas?

Tags: cas

I used `CAS server 4.0` and `cas-overlay-server-demo`. the return value of my server is as following:

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas="xxx">
    <cas:authenticationSuccess>
         <cas:user>try</cas:user>
    </cas:authenticationSuccess>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

I want to add `<cas:attributes>` to this return result. I have following code in `deployerConfigContext.xml`:
primaryAuthenticationHandler:

```
<bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AcceptUsersAuthenticationHandler">  
        <property name="users">  
            <map>  
                <entry key="test" value="1234"/>  
            </map>  
        </property>  
    </bean>
```

primaryPrincipalResolver:

```
<bean id="primaryPrincipalResolver"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver" >
        <property name="attributeRepository" ref="attributeRepository" />
    </bean>
```

attributeRepository:

```
<bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao"
            p:backingMap-ref="attrRepoBackingMap" />

    <util:map id="attrRepoBackingMap">
        <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
        <entry key="prénom" value="eduPersonAffiliation" /> 
        <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
    </util:map>
```

I think I have add the the code right. `StubPersonAttributeDao` will help me to add attributes: uid and prénom and groupMembership. BUT, I still do not get any attibutes. Is there anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to authorize your application in CAS service registry to release attributes. By default, nothing is allowed. See http://apereo.github.io/cas/4.0.x/integration/Attribute-Release.html